# Simple html/css Qu - how to I get two font sizes on the same line?

Tags: html, css

I want to have a span and with in that span I want there to be two different sizes of text. But I want them to be beside each other.

I've tried putting two spans beside each other, i've tried putting them inside a div, I've tried putting them in seperate divs, I've tried floating them...

Can't make it work :(

I know it's probably dead simple, can any kind soul help?

It's all part of a fading in div, heres the code:

```
<div id='message' style="display: none;">
    <span class="big">Wow, that was quick! </span><span>- below is a preview of your page, fill the form below and click publish.</span>
    <a href="#" class="close-notify">X</a>
</div>
```

css:

```
#message {height:30px;width:100%;z-index:105;text-align:center;color:white;padding:10px 0px 10px 0px;background-color:#8E1609;display:inline;}
#message span {text-align: center;width: 95%;float:left;}
.close-notify {white-space: nowrap;float:right;margin-right:10px;color:#fff;text-decoration:none;border:2px #fff solid;padding-left:3px;padding-right:3px}
.close-notify a {color: #fff;}
.big{font-size:1.3em;}
```

javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#message").fadeIn("slow");
    $("#message a.close-notify").click(function() {
        $("#message").fadeOut("slow");
        return false;
    });
});
```

Answer (score 2):

that happens because your first `span` has `width: 95%`. Just remove it and everything will work fine

http://jsfiddle.net/qcnZA/

Answer (score 0):

Two spans works great for me.  There's probably another reason you couldn't make it work.

```
<div>
    <span style="font-size:10px">Small</span>
    <span style="font-size:20px">Big</span>
</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/TUCr6/1/

Comment: really sorry about the lack of formatting, I can't see how to format during the comments.

Comment: @sammy sausage: You should edit that HTML/CSS into your original question.

Answer (score 0):

Could you post your code?

```
<span class="bold">Bold</span><span class="red"> and red</span>
```

should be displayed on 1 line, provided parent element is inline.

Comment: I posted the code in the comments for the other answer. Sorry bout lack of formatting. The parent is display:none coz I fade it in with javascript. I changed it to inline but that didn't help :(